# Проверьте правильность расстановки знаков препинания в этом предложении

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> Вперед вышел самый высокий и, лицемерно улыбаясь, ответил по-арабски, сопровождая речь жестикуляцией: «Ты наш гость, иди с миром, спасибо за визит», – при этом хитро подмигнул сотоварищам.

Comment: "Визит" тут нормально выглядит? Посетил с дружественным визитом? А "спасибо за визит" говорят обычно посетителю в офисе.

Comment: @Niemand, Он ведь говорил по-арабски, как бы Вы это перевели?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: @М_Г, кто это "он", который говорил по-арабски? Герой, которого придумал автор. Так что пусть он говорит хоть по-табасарански, но русский текст должен быть нормальным русским текстом, а не какой-то дикой смесью разговорного, канцелярита и еще бог знает чего.

Comment: Персонаж не вымышлен: мой жанр - путевые заметки (документалистика).

Comment: Это не имеет значения – вымышлен он или нет. Писать по-русски надо нормальным русским языком, иначе ваши "путевые заметки" никто не станет читать.

Comment: Предположим. А где исправленный (или альтернативный) вариант?

Answer (score 1):

**Вперед вышел самый высокий и, лицемерно улыбаясь, ответил по-арабски, сопровождая речь жестикуляцией: «Ты наш гость, иди с миром, спасибо за визит», при этом хитро подмигнул сотоварищам.**

Тире не нужно, после прямой речи следует заключительная часть сложного предложения (***при этом*** в роли присоединительного союза), поэтому ставится запятая.